# JQuery traverse up then down

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div>
    <button class="buttonClass">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div>
    <form id="formID">...</form>
</div>
```

When the form is submitted I want to simulate a click on the button with class `buttonClass`

This is what I'm trying but it's not finding the button and simulating the click:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    context:this,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        $(this).closest('.buttonClass').click(); // not finding button
    }
});
```

There are several forms and buttons on the page so I only want to click the nearest `buttonClass`

Comment: What is `$(this)` in the context of that code you gave? The form?

Comment: Yeah $(this) is the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `$(this)` in current context is refering to form element. you can use:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('.buttonClass').click();
```

Comment: This will work perfectly if the HTML stays as it is. Add another div inbetween or wrap another around the form and you're screwed. Darren if nothing is going to change, use this answer.

Comment: Yeah the html is fixed, great answer! Many thanks Popnoodles for answer too

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$(this)` is the form, since you're using `$(this).serialize` `$(this).closest('.buttonClass').click()` can't find the button because it's not an ancestor of the form, it's elsewhere.

You need an ancestor that contains both the form and the button to traverse to

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <button class="buttonClass">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form id="formID">...</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

then you can find it

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.buttonClass').click();
```